# Неправильно определенный цикл for

Tags: c, for

начал изучать C. но тут возникла проблема, не понимаю как ее решить и что я конкретно делаю не так. Visual Studio говорит следующее:
"C6294: Неправильно определенный цикл for: исходные условия не удовлетворяют условиям проверки. Тело цикла не выполняется."

код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* печать таблицы температур по Фаренгейту и Цельсию */

main()
{
    int fahr;
    for (fahr = 300; fahr <= 0; fahr = fahr - 20)
        printf ("%3d %6.1f\n", fahr, (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahr - 32));
}
```

Comment: У вас сразу же, при первой же проверке **НЕ** выполняется условие цикла, так что он не будет выполнен ни одного раза...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У вас сразу же, при первой же проверке **НЕ** выполняется условие цикла, так что он не будет выполнен ни одного раза...

```
for (fahr = 300; fahr >= 0; fahr = fahr - 20)
    printf ("%3d %6.1f\n", fahr, (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahr - 32));
```

См. https://ideone.com/lQtXPR

Comment: Большое спасибо! Понял в чем заключалась моя ошибка.

Comment: @xxx Не забудьте пометить ответ как решение.